# with a touch screen can you get the copy option by touching the screen

Tags: touchscreen

if i hold down my mouse i get a paste, copy, etc. yet when holding my finger on the screen nothing appears to happen, is there a certian secret way i should know about.. or? :/ :0

Comment: What OS? Is this on a tablet? Is there a pen? We really need a little more information

Comment: Touch screens usually do not have a copy option. You might get something displayed if you hook it up to a computer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've used a touch screen a few times at work and to bring up the menu you are looking for, try tapping the screen once, then again and hold. So it's a tap, release, then tap again and hold.

Comment: again: What OS? Is this on a tablet? Is there a pen?

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the type of touchscreen technology. Dispersive signal technology (piezoelectric) and acoustic pulse recognition types can't detect a motionless finger after the initial touch since they depend on the piezo electricity or the sound that happens when the touch occurs. Other touch technologies might be better suited to your need. See the Wikipedia article on touchscreens or peruse the information at www.elotouch.com who manufacture touchscreens.

Comment: besides this can provide interesting information, doesn't seem to solve to problem mentioned in the question: how to access the menu?